# How do you convert the result of a MySQL query into an integer in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried changing the result of a MySQL query to an integer with `intval()`, but I got an error saying it could not be changed to an int. Why I want to do this is to obtain the value of one of the fields in the database, minus one from it, and update the field with the new value. How would you do this with PHP?

Comment: If you want people to fix your code, you have to show them your code! `intval` doesn't have a bug, so it's your code that does.

Comment: @Dan Grossman I wasn't necessarily wanting people to fix my code, I just wanted to know what the right method was and was letting them know what method I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do it in PHP. Subtract one in the `UPDATE` query itself.

```
UPDATE table SET column = column - 1
```

Don't forget a `WHERE` clause if this is only supposed to update specific rows.